# How to implement Notification based on user's action in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my web application, based on some action happened from user, in my case whenever the details are exchanged between two users, backend will send a notification message to Front End. I need to display that message in UI like a message in a pop up. Upon closing the modal, the notification should disappear and appear again if the data is shared between the two users again.I am not sure if I have to use service workers for this. I have a React application, not sure if making an api call on every page load will help. Can someone let me know how can I implement this.
My Notification api-

```
{
            "name": "http://localhost:8056/getnotifications?username=harveyspectre&policyno=11111",
            "request": {
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:8056/getnotificationsusername=harveyspectre&policyno=11111",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "8056",
                    "path": [
                        "getnotifications"
                    ],
                    "query": [

                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "Harvey Spectre",
                            "equals": true,
                            "description": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "policyno",
                            "value": "11111",
                            "equals": true,
                            "description": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "variable": []
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "body": {},
                "description": ""
            },
            "response": []
        }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Check this link you can receive fcm push notifications on index.html file. After that you can send your notification data to your appropriate React screen using custom events.

Comment: But it has to listen continuously to the event on all the screens.

Comment: If your requirement is to just show as modal then you can directly do on index.html file. No need to pass custom events.